# Reference books for mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, anova, references, sas

I am looking for reference to get a better understanding and overview of the mixed models. My goal is to understand the basic concepts and the formulas behind different models (I am having a hard time understanding the proc mixed output in SAS). Below are some points that I would like to know:

- How to correctly construct the mixed model in different situations and objectives.
- Fully understand the results of the models (can reproduce the results manually).
- How to calculate the sample size for my studies.

Can you suggest good books (ideally in SAS)? Or maybe just help me get some orientation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only book that I'm familiar with that's specific for SAS is:

Stroup, W.W., Milliken, G.A., Claassen, E.A. and Wolfinger, R.D., 2018. ***SAS for mixed models: introduction and basic applications***. SAS Institute.

This is a very good, albeit brief, online guide from UCLA

[REPEATED MEASURES ANALYSIS USING SAS](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/seminars/sas-repeatedmeasures/)

A general mixed model theory and practice, and for other software, I can highly recommend the following books:

Demidenko, E., 2013. ***Mixed models: theory and applications with R.*** John Wiley & Sons.

Jiang, J. and Nguyen, T., 2021. ***Linear and generalized linear mixed models and their applications***. Springer Nature.

McCulloch, C.E. and Searle, S.R., 2004. ***Generalized, linear, and mixed models***. John Wiley & Sons.

Pinheiro, J. and Bates, D., 2006. ***Mixed-effects models in S and S-PLUS***. Springer Science & Business Media.

Rabe-Hesketh, S. and Skrondal, A., 2008. ***Multilevel and longitudinal modeling using Stata***. STATA press.

Raudenbush, S.W. and Bryk, A.S., 2002. ***Hierarchical linear models: Applications and data analysis methods***. sage.

Snijders, T.A. and Bosker, R.J., 2011. ***Multilevel analysis: An introduction to basic and advanced multilevel modeling***. sage.

Twisk, J.W., 2019. ***Applied mixed model analysis: a practical guide***. Cambridge University Press.

Comment: Thank you Robert for the list :)