# random effects variance meaning

Tags: mixed-model

I am trying to better understand the output for a multi-level mixed effects model. Specifically, I am confused on how to interpret the random-effects parameters, and the random effects variance. Is there something I should look for here to confirm the model is working as it should? And should I report this value in an output table, or is it more of an embellishment to include?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Parameters for `_cons` being a random effect means that the model assumes it to be a Gaussian random variable with a mean equal to zero and variance equal to `var(_cons)`. The parameters for each of the levels of `_cons` are assumed to be realizations of this random variable. So this is what the model estimates. Check the [What is the difference between fixed effect, random effect and mixed effect models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-effect-random-effect-and-mixed-effect-mode) thread or one of [many books](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/539218/reference-books-for-mixed-model) for more details. The variance would be "wrong" if it would be zero, infinite, or not a number, but otherwise, the values would depend on your model and the data.

Comment: Thank you for those references! I guess, a follow up question I have is: is there significance / readily interpretable meaning that this is much higher than the coefficients for variables specified in the model?